# How can I use Regex to validate 'num.numxnum.num' syntax?

Tags: javascript, regex

Day 353 - still stuck with RegEx

I am just simply not getting through with jQuery Regex

I would like to test syntax `9.3x1.3` where the nums can be any amount like `12.5x11.3` is also accepted, the important part is that it must be one or two num dot num x one or two num dot num

I online tested the `/[0-9].[0-9][x] [0-9].[0-9]` version online but doesnt seems to be working in RL. RegEx seems to be an out-of-world thing to me…

Comment: You have an extra space after `[x]`.

Comment: You have to escape `.` with backslash to match it literally. You don't have to put `x` inside `[x]`.

Comment: You're missing the ending `/`.

Comment: Regular expressions have nothing to do with jQuery, they're just vanilla JavaScript. Please post your code that isn't working.

Comment: Your regexp only matches 1 digit in each position. Use `\d+` to match any number of digits.

Comment: `\d+\.\d+x\d+\.\d+`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to match i.e: `2x100.3`? Just out of curiosity... what is that you're building? Seems like an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) posted this way - without any explanation....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this works for you `\d` is a convenience syntax for `[0-9]`

`/^\d{1,2}\.\dx\d{1,2}\.\d$/`

This should match the syntax described: one or two num dot num x one or two num dot num

[image]

**Edit:** added test

```js
const correctText = '12.3x9.1';
const incorrectText = '120.3x9.1';
const matcher = /^\d{1,2}\.\dx\d{1,2}\.\d$/;

console.log('correctText match result: ', matcher.test(correctText)); // should output true
console.log('incorrectText match result: ', matcher.test(incorrectText)); // should output false
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  
  let testSin = "12.3x9.1";
  let pattern = new RegExp( "/^\d{1,2}\.\dx\d{1,2}\.\d$/");
  
  if(pattern.test(testSin)) {
      alert("working");
} else {
      alert("nope");

}
  

});

Any problem with that then…?

Comment: @Tibi I have edited the answer with the JS code to test the expression

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was in the right direction, it only missed the valid length of each section.

`[0-9]` means one digit is allowed. Need to use `{min, max}` to set valid length.

It should be like this :

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9][x][0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]$/
         ^                  ^
         Here we say that length can be 1 or 2
```